# How to convert a single Oracle datetime into minutes?

Tags: sql, date, plsql, oracle11g

I wish to convert a single Oracle datetime value to minutes.

As an example, I need to convert the current date/time alone into minutes, i.e.:

```
select (sysdate)*24*60 from dual
```

but this is giving me an error.

I basically need to perform a check to see that a certain operation cannot be performed until 30 minutes before a particular date/start time, that exists in the database.

So if the Start Time in the DB is:

`24/04/2014 22:00:00 and the current date/time (SYSDATE) is 24/04/2014 21:29:59`,

then operation CANNOT be performed but if the current date/time (SYSDATE) is:

`24/04/2014 21:30:00`,

then operation CAN be performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like

```
startTime - interval '30' minute >= sysdate
```

or

```
startTime >= sysdate + interval '30' minute
```

You could also subtract the two `date` values which gives you the number of days between them and multiply

```
(startTime - sysdate)*24*60 >= 30
```

but I generally find the interval notation clearer and easier to read.  It's also easier to structure in a way that allows you to use indexes on columns like `startTime`.

Answer (score 1):

*select (sysdate - trunc(sysdate)) *24 *60 from dual*

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to know if the seconds component of `sysdate` is `0`.  So, test for that:

```
where extract(second from sysdate) = 0
```

Oops, I misread the question.  You just need a difference of 30 minutes.  That is also easy:

```
where starttime <= sysdate + 30/(24*60)
```

When you add an integer to a `datetime`, it is interpreted as a number of days.  The expression `30/(24*60)` is an expression for half an hour measured in days.